How to simply force the first frame to be a key frame without re-coding?
I tried an extensive search here and found a number of similar questions, including answers. However, none does a fast (and dirty?) and quick job. e.g.:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,0)" output.mp4

All solutions that I saw involved some sort of re-encoding. Since I have a large number of files that for one reason or another fail at different applications with e.g. ffprobe:
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55b5ab388ec0] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1024
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55b5ab388ec0] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 1024.

, I am looking for a -c copy solution that forces the beginning of keyframes to 1. I wouldn't mind slight corruption in the first frames. But like this, kdenlive bails out, and VLC starts at times with several seconds of delay, a first second of all green, or whatnot.
